# Putty doesn't have any colors, but only for one server

Tags: debian, colors, console

I'm using Putty to connect to 7 servers.

The problem is that one of them doesn't have any colors, which makes it harder to distinguish folders from other files.

Here's what I'm talking about.

Server with colors:

[image]

The server without colors:

[image]

What could be the problem that it doesn't have any colors? I'm using Debian 8.3 for both of them and I don't think I've changed anything that could affect this.

Comment: On the first server, is `ls` an alias to `ls --color=auto`? See it with `type ls`. Or just try `ls --color=auto` on the second server.

Comment: Yes, it is! But what about this `root@s /var/www/alexeu #`, which is also colored for the first server?

Comment: Different `$PS1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. My `~/.bashrc` file was empty. I have copied the one from `/etc/skel` and uncommended `force_color_prompt=yes` in it. Now it's all colored.